# Google Analytics Dashboards

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

I am a google analytics user. I created dashboards (on desktop). I just downloaded the mobile app and when I go to dashboards, there is nothing there even though everything else on the app is the same. Any suggestions? google-analytics

Answer (score 0):

Dashboards on the mobile app are not the same thing as the dashboards you created on the desktop version. Those are the collection of the reports you created in the mobile - pretty much just a shortcut to them.

There is nothing you can do about it, to pull the desktop version to the mobile.